# Webpack doubles text on minimization

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-5

I use Webpack to minimize JavaScript;
This code

```js
let a = "a";
let b = "b";
let c = "c";
let r =  a + `${b}` + ("[IT_DOUBLES]" + c + "d");
console.log('r = ' + r);
```

results to minimized

```js
let i="a",o="b",a="c",s=i+`${o}[IT_DOUBLES][IT_DOUBLES]`+a+"d";console.log("r = "+s);
```

And the wrong result is shown in the console:

```
r = ab[IT_DOUBLES][IT_DOUBLES]cd
```

Is there any problems in minimization or any guides for writing correct JS, that can be minimized?

npm 8.19.2

webpack 5.74.0

Comment: While that is a weird bug, why would you need to combine template literals and `+` string concatenation like that?

Comment: Ugh, awful bug. Please report the bug to the Webpack project.

Comment: The question *"Is there any problems in minimization or any guides for writing correct JS, that can be minimized?"* is off-topic here. Please see [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic)

Comment: For the bug report: I can't replicate the issue with exactly the source code shown, but I can with ```let a = "a"; let b = "b"; let c = "c"; function example(a, b, c) { let r = a + /`${b}/` + ("[IT_DOUBLES]" + c + "d"); console.log("r = " + r); } example(a, b, c);```

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, please provide me the correct site for asking about writing correct JavaScript for minimizing it with Webpack, if Webpack is an offtopic on stackoverflow.com. Thank you!

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, I reprodused a part of the code that consists inside a function. So being inside a function may matter.

Comment: @SergeyBeloglazov - I don't happen to know of any such sites.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, OK. I waited any reaction for my question, e.g. bad examples, unclear question, lack of data. But I it was surprise to me that Webpack is an offtopic on stackoverflow.com. When I wrote a tag, I saw webpack tags have thousands count. So it's still strange, why it's offtopic. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webpack - 42608 questions.

Comment: *Webpack* is on-topic, it's asking for general suggestions that isn't. Please see the links I provided. Also note that *just* putting the code in a function isn't sufficient. You have to do something to make Webpack think it can't inline the entire thing. My example above does that, but it's probably more than is needed. Anyway: **Awful** bug, I can only imagine (and empathize about) the time it cost you to figure out where that was. :-| We tend to trust our tools not to do that kind of thing. Good luck with it!

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, thank you for clear explanation! I understand that poor-formed question affects the answers.
Thanks a lot for finding the real whole example for the bug. Not a piece of a big undisclosed code like I did ;) I spend some time to rewriting the real piece of code to the minimized abstract one. But not the entire project, than can be put directly for Webpack.